# Save Mouse Event Recording to File for Future Use

Tags: python

I am using the `mouse` library to record mouse movements and clicks. I would like to be able to save the output to a file for future use. The file format doesn't matter, I just want something that loads quickly.

What's the best way of doing this?

Here's an example of the output:

```
[MoveEvent(x=388, y=775, time=1636642238.2061203), MoveEvent(x=389, y=781, time=1636642238.2121139), MoveEvent(x=390, y=787, time=1636642238.2201338), MoveEvent(x=390, y=794, time=1636642238.2281408), MoveEvent(x=390, y=798, time=1636642238.236148), MoveEvent(x=390, y=803, time=1636642238.2441564), MoveEvent(x=389, y=807, time=1636642238.252164), MoveEvent(x=387, y=810, time=1636642238.2601721), MoveEvent(x=385, y=813, time=1636642238.2681794), MoveEvent(x=382, y=816, time=1636642238.276187), MoveEvent(x=379, y=817, time=1636642238.2841942), MoveEvent(x=373, y=819, time=1636642238.2922027), MoveEvent(x=368, y=820, time=1636642238.3052194), MoveEvent(x=361, y=820, time=1636642238.3082435), MoveEvent(x=353, y=821, time=1636642238.316295), MoveEvent(x=346, y=821, time=1636642238.3243196), MoveEvent(x=338, y=821, time=1636642238.3324163), MoveEvent(x=330, y=821, time=1636642238.340473), MoveEvent(x=323, y=821, time=1636642238.3484905), MoveEvent(x=317, y=821, time=1636642238.3565843), MoveEvent(x=310, y=821, time=1636642238.3646388), MoveEvent(x=303, y=821, time=1636642238.3727493), MoveEvent(x=299, y=821, time=1636642238.3807762), MoveEvent(x=296, y=821, time=1636642238.3878405), MoveEvent(x=292, y=819, time=1636642238.3958871), MoveEvent(x=290, y=818, time=1636642238.4039407), MoveEvent(x=288, y=817, time=1636642238.4119675), MoveEvent(x=287, y=815, time=1636642238.4200554), MoveEvent(x=286, y=814, time=1636642238.4280841), MoveEvent(x=284, y=811, time=1636642238.4362218), MoveEvent(x=284, y=807, time=1636642238.4441965), MoveEvent(x=282, y=802, time=1636642238.4522853), MoveEvent(x=281, y=796, time=1636642238.460368), MoveEvent(x=278, y=790, time=1636642238.4684052), MoveEvent(x=275, y=783, time=1636642238.476566), MoveEvent(x=273, y=778, time=1636642238.484755), MoveEvent(x=270, y=772, time=1636642238.4928644), MoveEvent(x=267, y=764, time=1636642238.500874), MoveEvent(x=265, y=759, time=1636642238.507883), MoveEvent(x=264, y=753, time=1636642238.5159366), MoveEvent(x=263, y=749, time=1636642238.5240269), MoveEvent(x=262, y=744, time=1636642238.5320501), MoveEvent(x=262, y=740, time=1636642238.5401), MoveEvent(x=261, y=737, time=1636642238.5482757), MoveEvent(x=261, y=734, time=1636642238.5563776), MoveEvent(x=260, y=730, time=1636642238.5644212), MoveEvent(x=260, y=728, time=1636642238.5724287), MoveEvent(x=260, y=725, time=1636642238.580529), MoveEvent(x=260, y=722, time=1636642238.588673), MoveEvent(x=260, y=720, time=1636642238.5967886), MoveEvent(x=262, y=717, time=1636642238.604797), MoveEvent(x=265, y=713, time=1636642238.6128023), MoveEvent(x=269, y=711, time=1636642238.620836), MoveEvent(x=275, y=708, time=1636642238.6278546), MoveEvent(x=282, y=706, time=1636642238.6358633), MoveEvent(x=289, y=704, time=1636642238.6438715), MoveEvent(x=296, y=703, time=1636642238.6528707), MoveEvent(x=304, y=702, time=1636642238.6599228), MoveEvent(x=309, y=702, time=1636642238.6679506), MoveEvent(x=314, y=701, time=1636642238.6760018), MoveEvent(x=319, y=701, time=1636642238.684163), MoveEvent(x=323, y=701, time=1636642238.6923153), MoveEvent(x=325, y=701, time=1636642238.7003405), MoveEvent(x=328, y=700, time=1636642238.7084866), MoveEvent(x=331, y=700, time=1636642238.7164965), MoveEvent(x=333, y=699, time=1636642238.7245889), MoveEvent(x=335, y=699, time=1636642238.7327068), MoveEvent(x=336, y=699, time=1636642238.7407699), MoveEvent(x=336, y=699, time=1636642238.7487311), MoveEvent(x=337, y=698, time=1636642238.7882338), MoveEvent(x=337, y=698, time=1636642238.7963448), MoveEvent(x=338, y=698, time=1636642238.8043187), MoveEvent(x=339, y=699, time=1636642238.8124387), MoveEvent(x=339, y=700, time=1636642238.8205912), MoveEvent(x=339, y=701, time=1636642238.8286946), MoveEvent(x=341, y=704, time=1636642238.836814), MoveEvent(x=343, y=708, time=1636642238.844831), MoveEvent(x=346, y=713, time=1636642238.8518913), MoveEvent(x=348, y=716, time=1636642238.8600073), MoveEvent(x=350, y=718, time=1636642238.8681247), MoveEvent(x=351, y=720, time=1636642238.8761623), MoveEvent(x=351, y=720, time=1636642238.8842518), MoveEvent(x=351, y=721, time=1636642238.908614), MoveEvent(x=351, y=721, time=1636642238.9239602), MoveEvent(x=351, y=722, time=1636642238.9320507), MoveEvent(x=351, y=722, time=1636642238.9482505), MoveEvent(x=350, y=723, time=1636642238.9645796), MoveEvent(x=349, y=724, time=1636642238.9807267), MoveEvent(x=349, y=724, time=1636642238.9958973), MoveEvent(x=348, y=725, time=1636642239.0039878), MoveEvent(x=346, y=725, time=1636642239.0203187), MoveEvent(x=346, y=726, time=1636642239.0283906), MoveEvent(x=344, y=727, time=1636642239.036499), MoveEvent(x=343, y=727, time=1636642239.0526617), MoveEvent(x=342, y=727, time=1636642239.0687854), MoveEvent(x=341, y=728, time=1636642239.0759149), MoveEvent(x=341, y=728, time=1636642239.2687871), MoveEvent(x=340, y=729, time=1636642239.2759213)]
```

Comment: You might want to give [pickle](https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/) a try

Comment: Do you want the contents of the file to be human-readable/editable?

Comment: Hi @janq0 no, I just want to be able to run the recorded mouse movements using `mouse.play()`